# put echo into a variable with php

Tags: php, variables, echo

I'm having troubles with a function that create html from a csv file with php functions `fgetcsv()` and `echo`.

Here's the code:

```
<?php function getContent($data) {
    if (($handle = fopen($data, "r")) !== FALSE) {  
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            echo <p>...</p>
        }
    }
} ?>
```

It outputs an html table and then, I would like to use this with the function `fwrite()` to write it into a new html file that I just created. Now, I just tried to use it as a variable like this:

```
$content = getContent($data);
fwrite($file, $content);
```

But it's not working... Any idea ?

P.S: I have a lot of `echo` in the getContent function, this is why I don't want to use a variable.

Comment: You haven't defined the file pointer `$file`

Comment: I did, I just put portions of my code

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I understand your current function does echo what you want, so I'm assuming your echo-line is modified for this example, and it contains something with that `$data` in real,right?)

Echo prints to screen, and you don't want that, so save it and return it as a string.
quick example:

```
function getContent($data) {
    $result = ""; //you start with an empty string;
    if (($handle = fopen($data, "r")) !== FALSE) {  
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
          $result .=  "<p>...</p>"; //add what you used to echo to the string
        }
    }
    return $result; //send your string back to the caller of the function
}
```

now you can call that function and do stuff with your string. First, test it with `echo`:

```
$content = getContent($data); //gets you the data in a string
echo $content; //echoes it, just like you did before.
```

if that works and you have something you can write your content to (that `$file` must be defined obviously, you can do what you did:

```
$content = getContent($data); //still gets you the  data
fwrite($file, $content); //writes it to a file.
```

Now, if the write doesn't work, you should debug that first with a string you hardcode, but that hasn't got much todo with the issue in this question.

Comment: $data is the name of the csv file!

Comment: I have "a lot" of echo in the getContent function, I just showed one line.. If I want to use $result I must concatenate it, it's not easy to use.

Comment: Not to be too rude about it, but that's bad luck. Echo sends information to your screen. You don't want that. You could do all sorts of tricks with content buffering and all, but in the end that's just hacks. You should separate the concern of "get the info out of the file" from "do something with that info", so you could re-use your function for both use-cases as I've shown. Bottom line is that your current design doesn't support your new functionality, so it needs a refactor. A bit of extra work, sure, but it'll pay off in the end. Next time you'll remember doing it from the start. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I eventually changed my `echo` with a variable `$text` that I concatenated like this `$text .= "<p>...</p>"`

Afterwards, I just needed to use this variable to create the html file.